Get another lattice adding edges
Given the following Hasse diagram of a lattice:

I believe that it is not possible to add some edges to the diagram to obtain another lattice without any meet-irreducible elements, except for the coatoms, but is there a way to prove it?

Indeed, it is not possible.
The reason is that in a finite lattice every element is a meet of meet-irreducible elements.
So if the lattice has $k$ meet-irreducible elements, it has at most $2^k$ elements in total.
Given that your lattice has $11$ elements, it must have, at least, $4$ meet-irreducible elements.
